# gsub numbers and +

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I'm saving a number with `params[:number].gsub(/\D/,'')`, but I don't want to strip the plus symbol: `+`

For example if a user saves number `+1 (516) 949-9508` it saves as `15169499508` but how can we preserve the `+` as `+15169499508`?

Comment: As far as I understand, you only want to keep a plus only at the start of the string?  Use `.gsub(/^(\+)|\D+/, '\1')`

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby `\D` is just an alias for `[^0-9]`. You may explicitly set `[^0-9+]`:

```
params[:number].gsub(/[^0-9+]/,'')
```

Comment: Or `[^\d+]` if you prefer the aliases.

Answer (score 4):

I understand you only want to keep a plus only at the start of the string. You need to use:

```
.gsub(/\A(\+)|\D+/, '\1')
```

Here, `\A(\+)` branch matches a literal plus at the start of the string. The second branch is your `\D` that matches all chars but digits, just with a `+` quantifier that matches 1 or more occurrences. The `\1` backreference restores that initial plus symbol in the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any syntactic rules, [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-delete) would work just fine:

```
'+1 (516) 949-9508'.delete('^0-9+') #=> "+15169499508"
```